# Converting bash shell script to html webpage?

Tags: html, bash, shell, scripting

How can I convert a bash shell script to an html webpage?

I'd like to see an example with a simple hello world program, so that I can convert my script to html webpage.

I dont want to use cgi-script.
Are there any other alternatives?

Also I want to know how run it in CentOS using Firefox.

Comment: A firefox extension might do the job, but writing a tutorial for one from the ground up is far too broad for a Stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use vim!

```
$ cat sum.sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A a
while read num str
do (
    IFS='|'
    set -- $str
    echo $4

    )
    ((i++))
done < f1
```

Open the file in vim and do:

```
:TOhtml
```

And the result is stored in a file called `sum.sh.html`

[image]

Disable line-numbers and change the color scheme to match your preferences.